# How to change a HTML Textbox with C#

Tags: c#, html, textbox, setattribute

I was wondering if anybody knew how to change the contents of a HTML TextBox with C# I have tried to use `body.SetAttribute("value", string)` but I did not get anywhere. An example of what I am trying to do is `<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="body" class="messages-reply-box text-box text new-message-body">`*String I need changed*`</textarea>` Here is what I got so far:

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
HtmlElement bod = doc.GetElementById("body");
bod.SetAttribute("value", "text");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change the Text of a Element inside your html page you should use `InnerText` property. This should work

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("body").InnerText ="text";
```

Comment: It should be webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("body").InnerText ="text";

Comment: Correct, I've copied the wrong tag from my example in VS